# Objects and getting parents methods

Tags: java

Here is the best way I could summarise my situation:

```
Class1 makes new Thread(new Class2)
```

Is there a way from inside objects 2 code I can access non-static public methods from object 1?

Not sure if I have explained myself enough but I can answer any questions that could help describe it better

Edit: To elaborate Class1 is a multithreaded server and Class2 is the WorkerClass and i want to access Class1.stop() to stop the server from inside the workerClass

Comment: You sure haven't explained yourself enough. Please elaborate

Comment: Add it as a parameter to the new object?

Comment: Class2 implements Runnable but it cannot find the symbol for the method in object1 when I try

Comment: Ok to elaborate Class1 is a multithreaded server and Class2 is the WorkerClass and i want to access Class1.stop() to stop the server from inside the workerClass

Comment: Then you would need to pass the `object1` reference to `object2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways to do this:

(1) Use an anonymous inner class:

```
public class Class1 {

    public void foo() {}

    public void bar() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                foo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

(2) Use a named inner class:

```
public class Class1 {

    public void foo() {}

    public void bar() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
    }

    private class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            foo();
        }
    }
}
```

(3) Pass `this` to the constructor of another top-level class:

```
public class Class1 {

    public void foo() {}

    public void bar() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnable(this));
    }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Class1 class1;

    public MyRunnable(Class1 class1) {
        this.class1 = class1;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        class1.foo();
    }
}
```